# Exception for no memory while parsing large XML file in SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I've read some articles on advantages of using SAX parser for parsing XML files in java over using DOM.
The one which appeals me the most (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828703/what-is-the-difference-between-sax-and-dom)) is that

> Sax is suitable for large XML File and The SAX parser does not loads the XML file as a whole in the memory.

But now as i've written a parser using SAX to derive the entities out of an XML file for a large file of almost **1.4 GB** it generates the following Exception.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; The parser has encountered more than "64,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.
```

What is the problem with the memory if the file as whole is not loaded in the memory.

How can i resolve the issue?

Comment: That is not a necessarily an actual memory limitation, but a protective measure against DOS-attacks like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs). If your input XML legally contains that many entities you can increase that limit in your parser. Look at its documentation.

Comment: what to you suggest me to do with this protective measure?

Comment: I thought I said that.

Comment: Should i look at the documentation of JVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the entity expansion limit with a JVM parameter:

```
-DentityExpansionLimit=1000000
```

Comment: Depends on how you are running your program. It's a command-line parameter.

Comment: this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360901/getting-parent-child-hierarchy-in-sax-xml-parser contains my code for the parser hope you understand how i'm dealing with it

Comment: Yes, but how are you RUNNING it. Are you typing java blah blah from the command prompt? Are you executing it via an IDE?

Comment: Under run configurations on the arguments tab it's called "VM arguments". That's where you want to add that.

Comment: Thank you so much that really worked. :) I'm really really great full to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also think about using StAX.

SAX is event driven and serial. It can handle large XML, but takes a lot of CPU resources.

DOM is taking the complete document in memory.

StAX is a more recent API. It is streaming over the XML. It can be seen as a cursor or iterator over the document. It has the advantage you can skip elements that you don't need (attributes, tags, ...). It is taking a lot less CPU resources if used properly.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html

With SAX, the XML push the events.

With StAX, you pull the XML to you.

Comment: Does this means all my efforts to create a parser (using SAX) that actually worked well for the files of smaller size is wasted?

Comment: No. You can stick to SAX if you have fixed your issue. I just wanted to inform you there is still another, modern way of parsing XML. Another advantage: with SAX u can only parse XML, with StAX u can also write XML.

Comment: And if you have written your SAX implementation with well chosen methods, maybe you can reuse a lot of code and try the StAX way to measure the difference in performance. U will be surprised, believe me: when used correctly and skipping unnecessary elements, your parse time will decrease drastically!

Comment: in the comment to an answer below, i have added a link for my code. You see that.

Comment: It's just a proposal! I can provide you a StAX snippet if you want. It is typically used in a certain pattern. I'll look it up and will edit my post with a small example.

Comment: That would be so nice of you. Please review my code and show me how stax can do it :) and then may be i migrate to stax.

Comment: Okay. Coming back to you later.

Comment: So you want a pretty print of your tags only?

Comment: My Overall goal is to turn my XML file into sql but first i'm working on getting entities so that i can create ER Diagram out of it.

Comment: Answer posted in your other question!